# Microsoft flows convert file to windows-1251 and save to OneDrive

Tags: xml, sharepoint, dynamics-crm, onedrive, power-automate

I have a problem with Microsoft flow, I generate file XML and save file to OneDrive, but flow saved to encoding UTF-8 its wrong for me and I need to change it.

How to change encoding saved/or save file  into windows-1251 or another one.

UPD:  [My simple flow, print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPaT5.png)

Example code

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<DECLAR xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="123.xsd">
<DECLARHEAD>
<C_DOC_STAN>1</C_DOC_STAN>
<LINKED_DOCS xsi:nil="true"/>
</DECLARHEAD>
<DECLARBODY>
<R01G1 xsi:nil="true"/>
<R03G10S>Поточна інформація</R03G10S>
</DECLARBODY>
</DECLAR>
```

Comment: You need to share how you generating XML file. XML files have a prolog statement where you can specify your encoding.

Comment: Hi, thx for you reply, I added example.